# Web-To-Case Checks?

Tags: web2case

I don't have any code to post, but I have a general SFDC capability question.  Is it possible to place any validations on the Web-To-Case integration so that only a certain number of Cases can be created based upon the value of a p[articular field?  For example, if I have 12 cases coming through the web-to-case integration, but I only want to create cases for the 5 whose Type = Support, can this be done before cases are created?  Would a Before trigger be able to handle tis type of scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all 12 cases are being inserted at the same time,  sure.. But I don't believe that it would be a good idea assuming on that.

If you would be able to get an aggregate off of Cases that have been inserted already it may be reliable, but is there more to this you haven't mentioned?

Comment: The issue I am afraid of is that the standard Web-To-Case action will create a Case for every alert that our system generates.  Conceivably (though not highly likely), this could hit the 5k Case limit per day.  To avoid that, I was hoping to filter the cases created in some way, pre-insertion.

Comment: Interesting problem, It sounds like the standard solution of Web-To-Case may not be the way to go here

Comment: Yes, we are using the Web-To-Case.  I have a Process Builder / Flow solution developed that checks new cases against existing open cases with the same internal identifier.  If found, a new custom object record is created and associated to the existing case and new case is deleted.  If not, the new Case is kept and the custom object record is associated to that.  Problem is we could hit the 5k limit for Cases per day, so was hoping to somehow nip that before creating the Cases.